# How do you extract set elements in postgres?

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql

Let's say I extract some matches from a `regexp_matches` call.

How do I actually WORK with sets to do something with whatever I matched?

I.e. I'm looking or something like this

```
WITH raw_matches AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT regexp_matches(f.bar, 'my-fancy-regex', 'g') AS match
    FROM foo f
)
SELECT <do something with raw.match>
FROM raw_matches raw
;
```

Can I somehow expand a set into one record per entry or something?

Can I convert a set to an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called "arrays", not "sets", which may be the reason why you didn't find the appropriate documentation.

You need to perform a lateral join with the table function `unnest`:

```
... FROM raw_matches
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(raw_matches.match) AS u(element)
```